# Netsuite Suitelet addButton call function

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am struggling to find a way to add a button to a Suitelet that calls another function in the same suitelet.  I have tried many things but I can not get anything to work.  I also tried to create a client script and call the client script but the issue with that solution is I need to call another function in the Suitelet from the client script.

```js
function Image(request, response){
 
  var form = nlapiCreateForm("Today's Checks", true);

  function next(count){
    //code here
    showImage(imageId);//call to another function
  }
  
  form.addButton('custpage_next','Next',"next();");
  response.writePage(form);
  
  showImage(id){
    //more code . . . 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suitelet runs server side. You need to enable client side code. 
Put the code you need into another file and use it to create a client script. 
Give it a useful id when you create it. You don't need to deploy the script. 
Then

```
form.setScript('customscript_clientscriptid');
```

Then you can use the functions from that file in your button code.

Comment: Thanks that really helped!  However now I need to set a field value on the suitescript form with a variable that was set in the client script.  I have tried  nlapiSetFieldValue(. . . ) but that does not seem to work.  How can I set a field value on the suitelet form from the client script?

Comment: I was able to figure out the solution to my comment above but I am unsure why it worked.  The field I am using on the form is an inline html field.  If I set the default value of my field using .setDefaultValue on the suitelet then I can set the value using the Client Script